# PL/SQL error receieved on making of an XML file

Tags: sql, xml, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to make an XML file using PL/SQL procedure by using the following code:-

```
create or replace directory temp_dir as 'C:\XML';
grant read, write on directory temp_dir to hr;

DECLARE
      doc  DBMS_XMLDOM.DOMDocument;
      xdata  XMLTYPE;

      CURSOR xmlcur IS
      SELECT xmlelement("Employee",XMLAttributes('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS "xmlns:xsi",
                                    'http://www.oracle.com/Employee.xsd' AS "xsi:nonamespaceSchemaLocation")
                                ,xmlelement("EmployeeNumber",e.employee_id)
                                ,xmlelement("EmployeeName",e.first_name)
                               ,xmlelement("Department",xmlelement("DepartmentName",d.department_name)
                                                       ,xmlelement("Location",d.location_id)
                                          )
                    )
      FROM   employees e
      ,departments d
     WHERE  e.department_id=d.department_id;

   BEGIN
     OPEN xmlcur;
     FETCH xmlcur INTO xdata;
     CLOSE xmlcur;
     doc := DBMS_XMLDOM.NewDOMDocument(xdata);
     DBMS_XMLDOM.WRITETOFILE(doc, 'temp_dir/myXML1.xml');
     EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20002,'Error writing out XML.');
   END;
```

but i am recieving following error:-

```
Line 185: ORA-29280: invalid directory path
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 41
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 478
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR", line 217
ORA-29280: invalid directory path
ORA-29280: invalid directory path
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XMLDOM", line 5292
ORA-06512: at line 23
```

what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you are trying to write to a file on the database server, right?  Not a file on your client machine?  `c:\xml` seems like a directory that might exist on your client machine, not on the server.

The [`DBMS_XMLDOM` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_xmldom.htm#ARPLS399) states

> Note: Before database startup, the read-from and write-to directories
>   in the init.ORA file must be specified; for example:
>   UTL_FILE_DIR=/mypath/insidemypath.
>
> Read-from and write-to files must be on the server file system.

It seems that `DBMS_XMLDOM` doesn't support directory objects.  It still seems to rely on the old `UTL_FILE_DIR` parameter.

Personally, I would probably convert the XMLType to a CLOB with the `getClobVal()` method and then use the `clob2file` procedure in the `DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR` package to write it out

```
DBMS_XSLProcessor.Clob2File( 
  xdata.getClobVal(),
  'TEMP_DIR',
  'myXML1.xml' );
```

which works on my system

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  DECLARE
  2    xdata  XMLTYPE;
  3    CURSOR xmlcur IS
  4    SELECT xmlelement("Employee",
  5                      XMLAttributes('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS "xmlns:xsi",
  6                                    'http://www.oracle.com/Employee.xsd' AS "xsi:nonamespaceSchemaLocation")
  7                     ,xmlelement("EmployeeNumber",e.employee_id)
  8                     ,xmlelement("EmployeeName",e.first_name)
  9                     ,xmlelement("Department",
 10                                 xmlelement("DepartmentName",d.department_name)
 11                                ,xmlelement("Location",d.location_id)
 12                                )
 13                      )
 14    FROM   employees e
 15          ,departments d
 16    WHERE  e.department_id=d.department_id;
 17  BEGIN
 18    OPEN xmlcur;
 19    FETCH xmlcur INTO xdata;
 20    CLOSE xmlcur;
 21    DBMS_XSLProcessor.Clob2File(
 22        xdata.getClobVal(),
 23        'TEMP_DIR',
 24        'myXML1.xml' );
 25*    END;
SQL> /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

If you actually want to fetch all the data from the cursor rather than just the first row, you'll need a loop

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  DECLARE
  2    xdata  XMLTYPE;
  3    CURSOR xmlcur IS
  4    SELECT xmlelement("Employee",
  5                      XMLAttributes('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' AS "xmlns:xsi",
  6                                    'http://www.oracle.com/Employee.xsd' AS "xsi:nonamespaceSchemaLocation")
  7                     ,xmlelement("EmployeeNumber",e.employee_id)
  8                     ,xmlelement("EmployeeName",e.first_name)
  9                     ,xmlelement("Department",
 10                                 xmlelement("DepartmentName",d.department_name)
 11                                ,xmlelement("Location",d.location_id)
 12                                )
 13                      )
 14    FROM   employees e
 15          ,departments d
 16    WHERE  e.department_id=d.department_id;
 17    l_clob clob;
 18  BEGIN
 19    dbms_lob.createtemporary( l_clob, true );
 20    OPEN xmlcur;
 21    LOOP
 22      FETCH xmlcur INTO xdata;
 23      EXIT WHEN xmlcur%notfound;
 24      l_clob := l_clob || xdata.getClobVal();
 25    END LOOP;
 26    DBMS_XSLProcessor.Clob2File(
 27      l_clob,
 28      'TEMP_DIR',
 29      'myXML1.xml' );
 30    CLOSE xmlcur;
 31* END;
SQL> /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: your procedure is working fine but it is only fetching 1 result. I have multiple results and i want them to be stored in xml.Thanks for the help

Comment: and if i use loop i get the following error:-Line 214: ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "XDB.DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR", line 317
ORA-06512: at line 23

Comment: @Namelus - It's only fetching the first row because you don't have a loop-- you're just fetching the first row from the cursor and closing it.